# Can't use FaceTime from app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an App where you can call a person via FaceTime. My problem is, when I click on my button for the FaceTime-call, FaceTime opens but there is always a message "animStartXXXXXXX is not available for FaceTime." (the XXXX are random numbers). If I then call the same person from the normal FaceTime-app it works.
The code for the FaceTime-call:

```
 NSString *facetimeString = @"facetime://";
[facetimeString stringByAppendingString:contactNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facetimeString]];
```

I get the contactNumber by selecting it from the Adressbook from within my App and it works fine with normal calls/SMS.
Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Have you checked that `contactNumber` is enabled for Facetime as written? I'm assuming from the variable name that it is a phone number, but the other person might have Facetime enabled for an e-mail address or the number could be missing country codes, etc?

Comment: Could you NSLog the contactNumber and post the results.

Comment: Well, I copied the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facetimeString]]; ` and there was written i should put a phone number after FaceTime://. The NSLog("%s",contactNumber); : 2013-11-18 12:04:55.553 VideoSms[367:60b] +4917656...

Comment: I think you should [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768869/launching-facetime-from-your-app) before moving ahead. People have reported appstore rejection of app using `facetime://` url.

Comment: I've already seen that but thanks for the warning.

Comment: try to remove all spaces from number, If not working then try to remove special character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think PAIR is using FaceTime for video chat.

Since FaceTime API is not available to developers, you should consider using [OpenTok iOS SDK](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-ios-sdk).

Here is a excerpt from GitHub site:

The OpenTok iOS SDK lets you use OpenTok **video sessions** in apps you build for iPad, iPhone, and iPod touch devices. This means you can use OpenTok video sessions that connect iOS users with each other and with web clients.

Comment: What is PAIR?

I just want the user to be able to call other people via FaceTime, I don't want to write FaceTime on my own.

Comment: Yet it costs $50 monthly, about what a standard developer earns in the same time. Is there no support from the official Apple api?

Answer (score 0):

It is official that you can use Native app URL strings for FaceTime video calls:

```
facetime:// 14085551234
facetime://user@example.com
```

Please refer to the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html

Though this feature is supported on all devices, you have to change the code a little bit for iOS 10.0 and above as openURL(_:) is deprecated.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl?language=objc

Please refer code below for the current and fallback mechanism, so this way it will not get rejected by Appstore.

```
      -(void) callFaceTime : (NSString *) contactNumber
      {
          NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString 
              stringWithFormat:@"facetime://%@",  contactNumber]];
        if (@available(iOS 10.0, *)) {
              [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URL options:@{} 
            completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
            {
              if (success){
                NSLog(@"inside success");
              }
              else{
               NSLog(@"error");
              }
           }];
       } 
       else {
       // Fallback on earlier versions

          NSString *faceTimeUrlScheme = [@"facetime://" 
                                       stringByAppendingString:contactNumber];
        NSURL    *facetimeURL       = [NSURL URLWithString:faceTimeUrlScheme];

    // Facetime is available or not
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:facetimeURL])
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facetimeURL];
        }
         else
        {
           // Facetime not available
           NSLog(@"Facetime not available");
        }   
    }
  }
```

in contactNumber either pass phone number or appleid.

```
   NSString *phoneNumber = @"9999999999";
   NSString *appleId = @"abc@gmail.com";
   [self callFaceTime:appleId];
```

[objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)  [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)  [facetime](/questions/tagged/facetime)