# How to make facetime call from Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facetime

I am developing an app in Swift for iPad that makes use of facetime.

I know Apple introduced [App projection (described about 3/4 of way down page)](http://www.macworld.com/article/2359380/ios-8-faq-what-we-know-so-far-about-apples-next-generation-mobile-os.html) (where one app can "project" itsself into another) in iOS 8. Is facetime capable of this, and if so, how do I access this functionality in swift?

If not, how does one use facetime from an app programatically otherwise? I found [this question about the Swift API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13768869/launching-facetime-from-your-app) that explained how to do it in objective C. How do I adapt that code to work in swift? When I use it as written, I get the error "Expected ; seperator"

Barring the above two, is there any other or better ways to program facetime functionality for a swift app?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you try and write it in Swift? Let's start there rather than turning SO into a code translation service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A bit more self-contained solution in **Swift**:

```
private func facetime(phoneNumber:String) {
  if let facetimeURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "facetime://\(phoneNumber)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    if (application.canOpenURL(facetimeURL)) {
      application.openURL(facetimeURL);
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you should be able to use `facetime("7178881234")` to make a facetime call.

Answer (score 6):

Allow me to answer my own question...

I originally used the following code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://tel-number"]];
```

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251259/how-to-use-openurl-for-a-phone-call-with-swift), and the [Apple Facetime API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/FacetimeLinks/FacetimeLinks.html), I determined that the proper code was :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "facetime://tel-number"))
```

I hope this helps anyone else in the future.